# cmd file that starts plink.exe from a nant script not working

Tags: nant, plink

I have a .cmd file that start plink.exe and runs several commands.
This works great if I open a command prompt and run the .cmd file.

It does not work when I call the .cmd file from an nant script.

Oh. the nant script is on a windows machine and the plink.exe is connecting to a linux machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the NANT script running under the same user, when you manually run it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys guys. The problem was that because nant script was running under a different user, a question was asked and there was no response so the script would just hang and time out. This has now been resolved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the NANT script running under the same user, when you manually run it? Make sure the user's have enough access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Do you notice any error messages? Perhaps it is not founding the command executable i.e. plink.exe in the PATH environment variable. 
You can put following in your .cmd file: 
echo %PATH% 
Compare what you get when you run directly on the prompt and run through nant script. Please also provide the plink command line you are using in the .cmd file.